# extract string content between parenthesis -> for eg: function_name((param1),(param2)) should give (param1),(param2)

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to get the whole string which is inside function fun5. For eg:

```
1.) fun5(hello union fun1(param1) union fun2(param2)) union fun3(param3) union fun4(param4)
```

should return -> `hello union fun1(param1) union fun2(param2)`

```
2.) fun3(param3) union fun4(param4) union fun5(hello union fun1(param1) union fun2(param2))
```

should return -> `hello union fun1(param1) union fun2(param2)`

I tried using below regexp:

```
import re
str = "fun5(hello union fun1(param1) union fun2(param2)) union fun3(param3) union fun4(param4)"

if re.search(r'(:?\W|^)(:?fun5)\(', str, re.IGNORECASE):
    exp = re.search(fun5\((.*?)\)', str, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
    print(exp)
```

But it doesn't work because of nested parenthesis inside.

Comment: `(?s)fun5((?=\()(?:(?=.*?\((?!.*?\2)(.*\)(?!.*\3).*))(?=.*?\)(?!.*?\3)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\2)[^(]*(?=\3$))` where group 1 contains the function parameters enclosed in paren's. i.e. `(hello union fun1(param1) union fun2(param2))`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/PPPAVy/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but tricky, to write a regular expression if you know the parentheses won't go any deeper than some finite number (2 in your examples). This is because regular expressions simply aren't designed for handling nested patterns. Some regex engines have extensions to allow arbitrary nesting of patterns, or to match text in nested parentheses specifically, but Python's doesn't.

So if you might have to deal with an arbitrary nesting depth, you can instead use a non-regex solution like the one below. Here, we find the first opening parenthesis, then scan character by character. Each time we find an opening parentheses, we increment the depth. Each time we find a closing parenthesis, we decrement the depth and check to see if we're at level 0. If we are, we have found the closing parenthesis that matched the opening parenthesis, and so return the result.

```
def deparen(text):
    start = text.find("(")
    if start < 0:
        raise ValueError("no opening parenthesis")
    depth = 0
    for i in range(start, len(text)):
        if text[i] == "(":
            depth += 1
        elif text[i] == ")":
            depth -= 1
            if not depth:
                return text[start+1:i]
    raise ValueError("too few closing parentheses")
```

Note that this doesn't handle quoted parentheses. For example, if there might be quoted strings in the text, those might contain opening and/or closing parentheses, which *should not count* in the nesting. The key to handling this is to detect the quoting characters and skip any characters inside quotes. But the quotes might be escaped and so you have to detect that, too... at some point it becomes easier to use an actual parser.

Answer (score 0):

How about this `.*fun5\((.*\(.*\))\)`